# Do you know why the select menu, input type text and textarea form elements are not appearing?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I want to have the layout at left but it appears the layout at right. Do you know why is not appearing in the select menu, input type text and textarea?

[image]

In the Question model there is this `getHtmlInput` method() that is used in the view to generate the form fields:

In the registration.blade.php the questions are presented with the code below:

```
@if ($allParticipants == 0)
    @foreach($selectedRtype['questions'] as $customQuestion)

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
            @if($customQuestion->hasOptions())
                {!! $customQuestion->getHtmlInput(
                    $customQuestion->name,
                    $customQuestion->options,
                    ($customQuestion->pivot->required == '1'),
                    'form-control',
                    $customQuestion->type)
                !!}
            @endif
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="participant_question_required[]"
                   value="{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}">
            <input type="hidden"
                   value="{{ $customQuestion->id }}"
                   name="participant_question_id[]"/>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Generated html:

```
public function getHtmlInput($name = "", $options = "", $required = false, $class = "", $customtype=false)
    {
        $html = '';
        $html .= $customtype == 'select' ? "<select name='$name' class='$class' ".($required?:" required").">" : '';


        foreach($options as $option) {
            switch ($customtype) {
    case "text":
        $html .= " 
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <input type='text' name='participant_question' class='form-control'". ($required?:" required") . ">".
            '    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">' . $option->value. '</label>'.

            "</div>";

        $html .= "<input type='text' name='participant_question' value='".$option->value."' class='form-control'" . ($required?:" required") . ">";
        break;
    case "checkbox":
        $html .= " 
                <div class='form-check'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='participant_question[]' value='".$option->value."' class='form-check-input'" . ($required?:" required") . ">".
                    '    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">' . $option->value. '</label>'.

                "</div>";
        break;
    case "radio_btn":
        $html .= " 
                <div class='form-check'>
                    <input type='radio' name='participant_question[]' value='".$option->value."' class='form-check-input'" . ($required?:" required") . ">".
            '    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">' . $option->value. '</label>'.

            "</div>";
        break;
    case "select_menu":
        $html .= "<option value='".$option->value."'>";
        break;
    case "textarea":
        $html .= "
          <div class='form-group'>
                <textarea name='participant_question' class='form-control' rows='3'" . ($required?:" required") . ">"
                    . $option->value .
                "</textarea>
        </div>";

        break;
            }
        }

        $html .= $customtype == 'select' ? "</select>" : '';

        return $html;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/za2LpgL7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You've got a couple of items that are stopping this from working.

First is not a code issue - you simply don't have any options on the object.  The code

```
@if($customQuestion->hasOptions())
```

fails since the customQuestion has no options attached.  Thus, the code for the input boxes never gets entered.  Create a test object an attach the options for sure.  This may or may not work, but it will get you to the next step of seeing if the `getHtmlInput()` function works.

On that note, the fiddle you set up is showing that the `getHtmlInput()` function is either missing some code or the object is missing the type parameter.  The function appears to be entering *options* for the select box, but no select tag.  You need to initialize the select in your function ( add the proper HTML `<select></select>` tags into the function ).  I see you've made arrangement for this by the final method parameter, `$customtype=false`, but it appears this is also **not set** coming in to the function.  If you look at the fiddle, we see:

```
<label for="participant_question">Select menu question</label>
<option value="opt1"></option><option value="opt1">
```

The `<select>` is never entered.  I don't think your code is too far off (though I don't know how the options got in the fiddle if there were none to pass the if check), I think you need to test your objects to see what they include -- make sure they have options, make sure they have that `$customtype` and that it is set as select for the first round.  If the customQuestion object has the right parameters this will allow you to properly test.

Comment: Thanks, but so do you know how to change getHtmlInput() to return also the form elemetns that have no options, that is, the textarea and input type text.

Comment: Yes, you can do this by removing the if-check $customQuestion->hasOptions() from the blade and putting it inside the getHtmlInput() function *after* you create the form elements like textarea or input.  You must make sure the customType is set, then based on that type, create the form element for the type, THEN check to see if there are options, and then run through the loop to create the option elements.  This gets a little messy doing this in php vs using MVC... but it can be done.

Comment: Like this? if ($this->hasOptions()) { case "checkbox": $html .= "  <div class='form-check'> <input type='checkbox' name='participant_question[]' value='" . $option->value . "' class='form-check-input'" . ($required ?: " required") . ">" .'    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">'

Comment: ' . $option->value . '</label>' . "</div>";break;case "radio_btn":$html .= " <div class='form-check'><input type='radio' name='participant_question[]' value='" . $option->value . "' class='form-check-input'" . ($required ?: " required") . ">" .'    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">' . $option->value . '</label>' ."</div>";break; case "select_menu":$html .= "<option value='" . $option->value . "'>";break;}

Comment: No, you are still checking to see if it has options *before* you are making the form elements.  So, there will be no elements at all if no options (same as before).  You must move the if check **after** the creation of the basic form elements.  So first part of the method would check the customtype variable and make the form element.  THEN, once the element is made, then enter the if($options !== '') check for options.  If there are options, THEN you can continue with the rest of the code as is to create the option elements.  This probably needs a refactor - most of the case textarea stuff

Comment: for example, needs to be moved to the top before the if-check.  Not sure you want to do this, but this will make those elements appear, which is what you were after.  Also - note my if-check - there is no $this, you have passed the options as $options variable :)